# How to add .Net 3.5.1 as a prerequisite in an Azure Devop YAML?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, yaml

We currently have a .Net solution being built on our custom agents. I just had to install a new agent and we noticed that the build was failing, because 2 of our tools were requesting it.

Is there a way to force the installation of .Net 3.5.1 inside the YAML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add .Net 3.5.1 as a prerequisite in an Azure Devop YAML?

You can take advantage of the custom capabilities defined for agents and demands specified in the build pipeline. As noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#capabilities):

> The agent software automatically determines various system capabilities such as the name of the machine, type of operating system, and versions of certain software installed on the machine. Also, **environment variables defined in the machine automatically appear in the list of system capabilities**.

Thus, your self-hosted agents can define some special environment variable, like:

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands: DotNetFramework_3.5
```

You could check the thread [Specify demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

Comment: Nice! WOuld this prevent jobs to be assigned to those machine or directly install it?

Comment: Just wondering, we also have wix as a prerequisite, what would we need to specify in the Demands in this case? 

Just wondering, because at some point we want to extends our builds with Microsoft-Hosted agents

Comment: @J4N, Will restrict the pipeline to only assign build tasks to machines that satisfy the demands rather than install it. Because installing it requires administrator privileges.

Comment: @J4N, You can fully customize it, as long as you give the correct path where the corresponding wix is located.

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I'm not sure I've understand what the "demands" does. Does it install the prerequisite or does it block the execution if it's not present?

Comment: @J4N, Block the execution if it's not present.

Comment: But then, for MS cloud agents, how would you install them?

Comment: @J4N, Since it needs the Admin premission, we could not installed it in the hosted agent, we have to use private agent instead.

Comment: I understand. It's a shame it require admin permission. Thank you for the support